# QT6 strange widget rendering when 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP' is defined

Tags: gnome, 22.04, qt

~~*(Note: This question was originally asked on [QT's forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/145923/xdg_current_desktop-with-qt6-strange-widget-behavior/2), without much help)*~~

We recently upgraded to Ubutnu 22.04, with QT 6.5.1 installed using the online installer.
When porting some of our older (QT <= 5) apps, I noticed a strange issue with buttons, and progress bars, (so far).

In the designer, when I add a new button or progress bar,
[this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3B6p.png) (After further testing, it's not only limited to button and progress bar. Several widgets are also affected).

When I run the app, [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgX9f.png)

Here's the real kicker, [this is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4gPX.png) when I resize/move the window

After posting the original question, I tried messing with the environment variables. I found two culprits

`GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated`

`XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME`

Running in an empty environment with `env -i ...`, and only specifying the `DISPLAY` variable without anything else, or even only just disabling these two in the IDE I'm using, I got the correct/expected behavior, the widgets/window looked identical to the preview in the designer.

Unfortunately, I can't `unset XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` in `.profile` "easily" without completely breaking my desktop environment, so that's a no-go.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Try different widget themes and/or style sheets. Use your desktop's widget theme selector for starters. And no, you definitely never want to mess with a user's environment such as `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`; that is for the user to decide, not an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading from QT6.5.2 to QT6.4.3 solved the issue